# Posts Aren't Showing in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, blogs

I've been stuck on this for two days now. I have set up my own blog and the posts are stored in a database. This page is for grabbing an old post based on it's ID. When I try to retrieve them, everything shows but the actual body.

This is the index in /posts/

```
<?php
include_once('grabPost.php');
$TEMPLATE_TITLE = "$POST_TITLE";
include_once("../inc/template.html");
?>
```

Then, this is the grabPost.php.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
$ID = $_GET['id'];
include_once('connectionMod.php');
$DBConnection = new MySQLi($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_DTBS);
function ReturnError($error){
    global $POST_TITLE;
    global $POST_BODY;
    global $TEMPLATE_CONTENT;
    $POST_TITLE="Oops!";
    $POST_BODY="<p>It looks like we had an error grabbing your post. The post may have been moved, deleted, or you may have an invalid link. If you <strong>know</strong> this shouldn't be happening, please contact a developer.<br><em>$error</em></p>";
    $TEMPLATE_CONTENT = "<h1>$POST_TITLE</h1>\n<hr size='2'>\n$POST_BODY";
}
if($ID == null){
    ReturnError("No post ID was provided.");
}
if($stmt = $DBConnection->prepare("SELECT `Title`, `Poster`, `Date`, `Body` FROM `posts` WHERE `ID`=?")){
    if(!($stmt->bind_param('i', $ID))){
        ReturnError($stmt->error);
    }
    else if(!($stmt->execute())){
        ReturnError($stmt->error);
    }
    else if(!($stmt->bind_result($POST_TITLE, $POST_NAME, $POST_DATE, $POST_BODY))){
        ReturnError($stmt->error);
    }
    else if(!($stmt->fetch())){
        ReturnError($stmt->error);
    }
    else{
        $TEMPLATE_CONTENT = "<h1>$POST_TITLE</h1>\n<small>Posted on $POST_DATE by $POST_NAME</small>\n<hr size='2'>\n$POST_BODY";
    }
}
else{
    ReturnError($DBConnection->error);
}
?>
```

Oddly though, you can see the most recent post without issue on the homepage. Any suggestions with what's wrong?
Also, ReturnError() never shows the error. What can I do about it?

Comment: pur `error_reporting(E_ALL);` as check if any error

Comment: I already had -1, but it made no difference. No errors are showing up.

Comment: what do you expect ReturnError() to do without a return or echo statement...?

Comment: $POST_BODY includes the error. If it fails, a webpage is still shown that says "Oops!" and should give information along with the error. When I did die() it worked, but I obviously don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the fix. I needed to run `$stmt->store_result()` before `$stmt->bind_result()` since since the body was a LONGTEXT, I guess this is some issue with MySQL and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

**Function**

```
function return_error($error){
$post_error = "<h1>Oops!</h1>\n<hr size='2'><br />"
              ."<p>It looks like we had an error grabbing your post."
              ."The post may have been moved, deleted, or you may have an invalid link."
              ."If you <strong>know</strong> this shouldn't be happening, "
              ."please contact a developer.<br><em>".$error."</em></p>";

return $post_error;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
/* check connection */
if ($DBConnection->connect_errno) {
    $error = return_error("Connect failed: %s\n", $DBConnection->connect_error);
    echo $error;
    die();
}

/* check prepare() */
$stmt = $DBConnection->prepare("SELECT ....FROM `posts` WHERE `ID`=?");
if(!$stmt){
    $error = return_error("prepare failed()".$stmt->error);
    echo $error;
    die();
}
```

and so forth ... By the way if connection fail or any other fatal error occurs, then `die()` or `exit()` is the right thing to do..

Comment: The error was just debugging for me, but still doesn't fix my main issue of the body not showing.

Comment: Meda I updated too to make myself more clear.
Errors are pretty much working, but the issue with the body still being blank is a large concern for me.